# Select full block of text delimited by some chars

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a very large text file (40GB gzipped) where blocks of data are separated by `//`.

How can I select blocks of data where a certain line matches some criterion? That is, can I `grep` a pattern and extend the selection in both directions to the `//` delimiter? I can make no assumptions on the size of the block and the position of the line.

```
not interesting 1
not interesting 2
//
get the whole block 1
MATCH THIS LINE
get the whole block 2
get the whole block 3
//
not interesting 1
not interesting 2
//
```

I want to select the block of data with `MATCH THIS LINE`:

```
get the whole block 1
MATCH THIS LINE
get the whole block 2
get the whole block 3
```

I tried `sed` but can't get my head around the pattern definition. This for example should match from `//` to `MATCH THIS LINE`:

```
sed -n -e '/\/\//,/MATCH THIS LINE/ p' file.txt
```

But it fails matching the `//`.

Is it possible to achieve this with GNU command line tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `GNU awk` (due to multi-char RS), you can set the record separator to `//`, so that every record is a `//`-delimited set of characters:

```
$ awk -v RS="//" '/MATCH THIS LINE/' file

get the whole block 1
MATCH THIS LINE
get the whole block 2
get the whole block 3
```

Note this leaves an empty line above and below because it catches the new line just after // and prints it back, as well as the last one before the // at the end. To remove them you can pipe to `awk 'NF'`.

To print the separator between blocks of data you can say (thanks [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123)):

```
awk -v RS="//" '/MATCH THIS LINE/{print RT $0 RT}' file
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Is it possible to retain the `//` and print it back to the output?

Comment: @MartinPreusse how exactly? Above and below the block?

Comment: Below. I.e. keep the separator between blocks of data.

Comment: @MartinPreusse ok then you can say `awk -v RS="//" -v ORS="//" '/MATCH THIS LINE/' file`

Comment: @fedorqui On GNU you could do `/MATCH THIS LINE/{print RT $0 RT}`. Otherwise the prompt will be on the same line as data.

Comment: Amazing, it runs in ~30 seconds on a 40GB file. Thanks!

Comment: You should mention this is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS.